# How can I enforce using a GORM data service instead of GormEntityApi

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

How can I enforce that all entity persistence operations in my Grails application happen via [GORM data services](http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/#dataServices), and never directly on my domain classes (e.g. the methods in `GormEntityApi` and dynamic finders)?

Ideally the `GormEntityApi` and dynamic finder methods would not be available on my domain classes at all, but I'd also accept a solution that neuters the methods by causing them all to throw e.g. an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

I've done a bunch of internet searches, pored over the GORM documentation, and even dug around in the GORM code a bit, and I can't seem to find any information about this. Since data services provide all the same CRUD functionality as `GormEntityApi` and dynamic finders, this seems like a reasonable thing to want to do. I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I enforce that all entity persistence operations in my Grails
>   application happen via a GORM data services

There is no way to enforce that right now.

> I've done a bunch of internet searches, pored over the GORM
>   documentation, and even dug around in the GORM code a bit, and I can't
>   seem to find any information about this.

We don't have support in the framework for doing that.

> Since data services provide all the same CRUD functionality as
>   GormEntityApi and dynamic finders, this seems like a reasonable thing
>   to want to do. I feel like I must be missing something.

I don't think you are missing something.  We have considered not adding the `GormEntity` trait to domain classes by default, but right now that happens and we don't provide a mechanism for turning that off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My two cents: Even if you continue to add the `GormEntity` trait by default, it would be nice to have a way to turn that off. (Even better, turn it off by default for domain classes that have a corresponding data service.)